# Why is JS file showing 404 error by browser in my C# MVC project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting a 404 error for a JavaScript file that, as far as I can tell, is referenced correctly. Here is the error in Chrome console:

[image: maps.js 404 error]

I am referencing a JavaScript file ("~/Scripts/maps.js") in the CSHTML file as follows:

[image: Index.cshtml]
The file is in the correct folder:

[image: Folder showing maps.js]

I really don't know where I am going wrong - I have checked, checked and rechecked the path & don't see what else what the problem could be.

Comment: a typo "map >> s <<  .js" actual name is map.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file name is `map.js` and you're referencing `maps.js`.

Comment: Thank you, this has been driving me crazy